# Alternative to Modulo operator

Tags: opencv, matrix, modulo

I am using OpenCV library. It doesn't have a modulo operator that can be applied to WHOLE matrix.
It has a Multiplication, Subtraction operators for a matrix.

Is there any way I can combine these operations to have an alternative to modulo operation?
I am looking for modulo of 2*pi.
If there are multiple of 2*pi in a row of matrix, the product of that row will be zero. It will ease my life and save considerable performance compare to looping every element of matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to apply a modulo operator to a whole matrix, if not applying it to each individual element?

Comment: OpenCV library has operators to be applied on whole matrix, which are highly optimized like Multiplication, addition, subtraction etc.
If we can make use of these operators directly to compute modulo of matrix (modulo of each element of matrix) that would be more efficient than going to each element and computing its modulo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've also got Division and Floor, you can use:

```
mod(a,b) = a - floor(a/b) * b
```